# What can cause the experimental power output to be lower than the theoretical one?

Tags: electric-circuits

For a lab experiment, I was tasked with finding the power output of the circuit below[image]

I am pretty confident that I measured all of the variables correctly (DMM). I have also gone over my notes several times and I'm pretty sure my equations are correct. However, for my theoretical input I got $1.78\pm 0.016$ watts as the theoretical power with $1.47$ watts as the experimental one.

What factors can cause this kind of discrepancy? The only ones I can think of are wire and battery resistance, but I don't think that by themselves they can produce such a large difference.

EDIT: Here are my theoretical equations. As stated, the resistances, currents, and voltages were all measured using a digital multimeter.
$$P_{total}=\frac{R_1V_2^2+R_2V_1^2+R_3(V_1+V_2)^2}{R_1R_2+R_1R_3+R_2R_3}$$$$\sigma_P=\frac{\sqrt{(R_2V_1+R_3V_1+R_3V_2)^4\sigma^2_{R_1}+(R_1V_2+R_3V_1+R_3V_2)^4\sigma^2_{R_2}+(R_1V_2-R_2V_1)^4\sigma^2_{R_3}}}{(R_1R_2+R_1R_3+R_2R_3)^2}$$ where $\sigma_P$ denotes the standard deviation of the power function $P$. Also, I found that the voltage output of the batteries did not change significantly over the course of the experiment so I assume $\sigma_{V_1},\sigma_{V_2}=0$

Comment: It would be useful if you outlined your theoretical equations, and your power measurement method.

Comment: Is this good? @Dlamini?

Comment: What voltages are you using?

Comment: @RyanGreyling much better.

Comment: $V_1$ is 5.66 volts and $V_2$ is 5.84 volts @JMac

Comment: You mean watts, not joules, right?

Comment: oh whoops, yeah I do mean watts

Comment: I'm just thinking about something, can you tell me the resistances too?

Comment: The resistors weren't labeled but I measured them each multiple times with the DMM. The averages are $R_1=63.8\: R_2=20.63 \: R_3=28.27$. Units are ohms.

Comment: Physically, what kind of device were the voltage sources? Batteries? Benchtop sources? Wall warts? Did you measure their voltages in-circuit or disconnected?

Comment: *"I was tasked with finding the power output of the circuit below"* - what is the *load* for this circuit?  Due to energy conservation, the sum of the powers absorbed by each circuit element is zero (if the power absorbed is negative, the circuit element is *supplying* power).  Is the 'power output' the total power absorbed by the resistors?  The power absorbed by one of the resistors?

Comment: The voltages were measured in-circuit. The actual experiment took place weeks ago, but I'm pretty sure one voltage source was a battery while the other was a large power supplier (the kind where you can turn a knob to adjust voltage and current). @ThePhoton

Comment: The Power output is the total power absorbed by all three resistors.

Comment: The battery will give 2 volt measurement when in or out of the circuit, there is an internal resistance to the battery under load.  This is where power loss can occur.

Comment: Thanks @PhysicsDave that's the kind of answer I'm looking for.

Comment: What is the precision of the dmm? What is the precise experimental setup (including all values). How did you account for temperature change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you're using for $P_{Total}$ is correct, it's from the wye-delta transform on the three resistors, after swapping the position of $V_2$ and $R_2$. It should work. And it should give you results accurate to a fraction of a percent.

I suppose you got the experimental power by summing $V^2/R$ over the three resistors but where did you get the voltage from? You should have got three different voltages, one for each of the resistors and obtained by measuring the voltage on each resistor. Again, this should be accurate to fractions of a percent.

The formula for the variance seems to include only variance in measuring the resistors. Seems to me that you'd also have to include variance in measuring the voltages.

One place where this sort of measurement could be wrong is failure to take into account the impedance of the voltage / resistance measuring device. Unless you're doing your lab using medieval equipment I don't see how this could contribute more than a tiny fraction of a percent.

Well sometimes you have to write up a lab report as a failure.

Comment: $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the voltages supplies by the two batteries, not the voltage drops across the resistors. You are right that each resistor experiences a different voltage drop, but since I assume the materials I'm using are ohmic I know that $V=IR$ and I've already solved the equations for each of the three currents.

Comment: Also, you're right that the full error formula should account for the two voltages. However, the voltages did not change over the course of the experiment so the corresponding terms in the error formula would just be $0$.

Comment: Of course $V_1$ and $V_2$ are the power supply voltages, not the resistor voltages. That's why you have a term $V_1+V_2$ in the power computation for that leg of the Delta. My question is about the "1.47 Watts", how did you compute that number? Of course since that's the part I don't understand it's where I pry.

Comment: So you computed the resistor currents. Do you have those numbers? The calculations are so much easier in Delta form that it's painful to imagine working them out in Wye.

Comment: The experimental value of 1.47 Watts was computed with $P_{total}=I_1^2R_1+I_2^2R_2+I_3^2R_3$ where the current values in amps are $I_1=0.11$ $I_2=0.17$ and $I_3=0.06$.

Comment: Can you redo with currents computed with two more digits accuracy? An immediate problem with the $P_{exp}$ calculation is that adding 0.005 amps to all the currents will be something like a 10% increase in the power. In other words, you undoubtedly need more digits of accuracy there, or you need to do a calculation on how much the error in current is effecting your experimental power calculation.

Comment: Hmm, that's a fair point. Unfortunately, I can't repeat the experiment. Thank you for your help.

Comment: So you measured the currents with a DMM and only recorded 2 digits accuracy? If that's the case, do a error calculation for the current (how much does $P_{exp}$ depend on errors in the current) and put 0.005 amps for the minimum error in current digitization error. Add that to your error in $P_{exp}$ and it should be within tolerance. Good hunting!